# Передача данных между Activity

Tags: android, разработка-игр, activity

Делаю игру-викторину, не могу понять как реализовать следующее: в главном меню несколько "комнат"(комната 1, комната 2), каждая комната содержит ряд вопросов. В начале активна и доступна только первая комната, а вторая становится активной если ответить на все вопросы в первой и так далее. Не могу понять как передать данные из activity1(где происходит сама игра), в Activity2(меню), для того чтобы сделать активным следующую комнату. 
Надеюсь доступно объяснил)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите [документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Передавать данные вы можете в extras *Intent*'а, используемого для запуска новой *Activity* (метод *startActivity*).

Для получения каких-то результатов по завершении запускаемой *Activity* (в вашем случае, прогресс прохождения комнаты), можете запускать её через *startActivityForResult*, соответственно, возвращая из неё данные вызовом *setResult*.

Для сохранения прогресса между запусками приложения можете использовать [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) или же БД.

Пример работы с *SharedPreferences*:

```
/* сохранение текущего прогресса */
context.getSharedPreferences("preferences_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("progress", 10).commit();

/* и извлечение где-то в нужном месте */
int progress = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("progress", 0);
```

Comment: А как сохранить общий прогресс? чтобы при каждом запуске не приходилось заново открывать "комнаты"?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, с интентами разобрался. Но можно поподробнее насчет сохранения прогресса через SharedPreferences? Как это должно происходить?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз!

Answer (score 0):

Создайте класс, который будет содержать статичное поле. И вы сможете использовать это поле везде.
Например:

```
public class a {
    public static int progress = 1;
    public static boolean canPlayLevel(level) {
        if(level <= progress) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

И когда игрок проходит комнату, инкрементировать progress.

Comment: И когда приложение будет находиться в фоне (будет свёрнуто), и системе понадобится высвободить память для активных задач, прогресс будет утерян. В общем, плохой совет.

Comment: > И когда приложение будет находиться в фоне (будет свёрнуто), и системе понадобится высвободить память для активных задач, прогресс будет утерян. В общем, плохой совет.
Можно сохранять процесс прохождения.

Comment: Вот только в вашем ответе этого не указано. Соответственно, если автор вопроса в точности последует вашему совету, то, впоследствии, столкнётся с неожиданными и непонятными для него проблемами.